# Binary search has index out of range exception but worked before

Tags: c#, exception, console-application

I am having this problem ,I get index out of range exception on this code for reason unknown. I have list of students that are converted to array and then I return the info for the students in type of String. getFN is  returning the Faculty Number (int) . The list is working fine, can it be because I have too little elements into it?
the exception is on this line:

```
error --> if (item > data[mid].getFN())

public string BinarySearch(int item)
    {

        int min = 0;
        int N = myList.ToArray().Length;
        int max = N - 1;
        Student[] data = myList.ToArray();
        do
        {
            int mid = (min + max) / 2;
            if (item > data[mid].getFN())
                min = mid + 1;
            else
                max = mid - 1;
            if (data[mid].getFN() == item)
                return data[mid].toString();
        } while (min <= max);
        return "Not found. ";
    }
```

Comment: If the list is empty, then you will always get an error when you try to retrieve an item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the array `data` at a specific index; '0' to get the first item, '1' for the next etc.

On that line where you see the error, you are trying to access the array at the index of `mid`, whatever value it is at that time. The error is telling you that there is no value at that index.

Maybe the array is empty, maybe your math is causing you to read an index higher than the last entry in the array.

Put a breakpoint on that line, and then mouseover `mid` to see what index you are trying to read, and over `data` to see what's in the array. You should see what's happening.